# Will 21 inch replacement blades fit a mower with blades that measure 20-5/8 inches?

Tags: lawn-mower

Mower is a belly mounted 60 inch mower mounted on a Mahindra emax 22. The mower is manufactured by Amerequip for Mahindra. Manual specifies three 21 inch blades; however, the aftermarket blades found on the mower measure 20-5/8 inches. I intend to replace; however, want to use appropriate aftermarket blades. Like 2x4 lumber, the 21 inch description might simply be a nominal reference, but, I want to be certain.

Comment: Get original blades and measure them.

Comment: Do you have an extra 3/8" clearance to the blade housing? Seems to me that's all that really matters.

Comment: If there is any amount of overlap, the blades will make a complete cut, even if they're shorter than prescribed. As soon as the leading corner wears, they will begin to leave an uncut strip. I just want to make sure that I'm using the maximum engineered length blade to get the most coverage out of them.

Answer (score 1):

My Mahindra has several similar differences. Not being made in the US the metric measurements are slightly different. With the measurements being just a couple of 8ths under will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if they are "nominal" in the way of lumber, or just not that precise in the way of cheap lawn mower blades.  The overlap between your blades will be reduced by 3/8 inches (Each blade is 3/16 inch short at each end).   The overlap between the paths of the blades is typically closer to an inch so you'll still have plenty of overlap.